# Bitmap image loading in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm facing memory problem with image loading in xamarin forms list view, now i need to implement bitmap image in forms but i cant do that in xamarin forms i can't find any namespace including  bit map in xamarin forms
i have a normal  data binding code which also binds image too

```
 public async void GetResult()
    //public  void GetResult()
    {
        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync(string.Format(Url));
            var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<cm_main_category>>(json.ToString());
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                 item.image_url = "http://somelink.net" + item.image_url.Substring(1, item.image_url.Length - 1);
               // item.image_url = "http://127.0.0.1" + item.image_url.Substring(1, item.image_url.Length - 1);
                ListItems.Add(item);
            }
            IsBusy = false;
        }
```

now i nee to  implement bit map to this code what should be the approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you want to bind the image by URI. That's pretty easy in Xamarin.Forms.

You simply need to bind the `ImageSourceProperty` of an `ImageCell` to the property that knows the URI.
A great example for both XAML binding and C# binding can be found here:  https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-listview-imagecell-recipe/

EDIT:
Copied from the comments: The solution is to set the image source to null and trigger the garbage collection as described here: [OutOfMemoryError when loading an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079620/outofmemoryerror-when-loading-an-image)

Comment: i can do that , and also i can populate listview  with images also but the problem  is  i can't add more data to it because of memory error and i need the image to bitmap  how can i implement bitmap image instead   of normal image

Comment: What is the _memory error_ you are facing? Do you receive an `OutOfMemoryException`? Then read this http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/

Comment: yes i am getting the OutOfMemoryException  how can i implement it on forms  that link is about native i need forms thank for your replay

Comment: I only know about memory issues reagarding images on android. Other users have already faced this problem. I think their solutions can help you
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807196/xamarin-forms-listview-outofmemeoryerror-on-android
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079620/outofmemoryerror-when-loading-an-image

Comment: Also try to set Java heap size to eg. 1GB in Android Project options. I think it will fix your memory issues.

Comment: i just collect the garbage then it works fine to me now thanks for your relay  is there anything wrong with that did it harm to my app ?

Comment: That doesn't harm your app. You just trigger the removal of unused memory. If the question is answered, then please accept the answer.

Comment: ** protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            BindingContext = null;
            Content = null;
            base.OnDisappearing();
            GC.Collect();
        }**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save memory, you could try to use FFImageLoading `CachedImage` which is `Image` API compatible replacement with advanced memory caching and downsampling capabilities. Just replace `Image` with `CachedImage` and set one of its downsampling properties.

https://github.com/molinch/FFImageLoading

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        BindingContext = null;
        Content = null;
        base.OnDisappearing();
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

on some app this will help if your app is dealing with thousands of data with image better adding bitmap